# Linux, Fedora 23: how to resolve installation/package conflicts

Tags: linux, installation, shared-libraries, gnome-terminal

I'll make this slightly generic in the hope that the solution might be more widely useful (assuming there is one).

I've been trying to run an app under Fedora 23 and which app is provided in the official repositories. It installs perfectly fine but won't start. Running it from the terminal tells me:

```
"unable to find <this.so>"
```

where

```
<this.so>
```

refers to a specific library that the app cannot find.

In following outside help, I've run a few terminal commands to try to narrow down the problem. If I try to install the apparently missing

```
<this.so>
```

by installing the package that provides it using

```
"dnf install <that.package>"
```

returns

```
"<that.package> is already installed. Skipping"
```

If I run

```
"$ locate <this.so>"
```

it comes back with (I'm now being specific):

```
/usr/lib/<this.so>
```

showing me that it believes the library to  be at that location.

If I run

```
"dnf provides <this.so>"
```

it again points to

```
dnf : system @root
```

If however I run

```
"rmp -Va"
```

one of the first returned items is

```
missing.... /usr/lib64/<this.so>
```

Again  seems to refer to the same instance but in a different location. So my question is:

How do I fix this discrepancy? The app tells me it's not installed, and locate tells me it is, and rmp tells me it's missing but from a different location.

I've obviously done plenty of "dnf clean all" "updatedb" and reboots. Anything else I could be trying?

Comment: Thoughtful first post! However, not sure if this is the best way to go, making it generic does not help someone recreate your issue. There may be package specific issues. Might I suggest you edit to be more specific. It will also clarify if it's in scope - a programming (or tool) related question, or one that may better belong with our admin or user friends  SuperUser or ServerFault

Comment: sorry for the delay! I've been distracted. Good point you make, and would be happy to oblige except that since posting (my issue was with Darktable) I had some help over there, and after advice from clearly very experienced users decided to delete and reinstall my entire system. Problem now resolved! (although not in any more helpful way, sadly)

Answer (score 0):

If the distro you are using is x86_64, you can have bot x86_64 and i686 libraries. If you list available packages with dnf you can see that there is a suffix on the packages names that indicate for what architecture they are used for.

For your case, i think you just need to reinstall the two versions of the package you need with:

```
dnf reinstall <that.package> <that.package>.i686
```

Comment: yes, thank you for this. I did in fact try this, but see above - I reinstalled the entire system!